# 機械学習を用いた各パラメータの重要度評価について

Tags: 機械学習

フリーソフト「Orange」を用いて機械学習を行っている大学生です．
現在，3つの入力値に対して6つの出力値が得られる問題について扱っています．
どのパラメータがそれぞれの出力値に対してどの程度寄与するのかを数値として知りたい(*)のですが，どの評価を用いてどのように考察していけばよいのか全く分かりません．

まず，(i)各特徴量の重要度(寄与率？)を評価するのはランダムフォレストになると考えているのですが，これは正しいでしょうか．また，(ii)ランダムフォレストを行う場合，Orangeソフト内で目的関数を複数の出力値に設定することができないようなのですが，(*)のような場合はどのように評価を進めればよいのでしょうか．そもそも，(iii)(*)を評価する場合は目的関数は出力値でよいのでしょうか．

以上，もし有識のある方がおられましたら，御助言をどうぞ宜しくお願い致します．

Answer (score 0):

Orange知りませんでした。まだ回答が無いようですので、答えられる範囲で回答致します。

「3つの入力値に対して6つの出力値が得られる問題」
というのが分かりません。
連続値を予測する「回帰」の問題でしょうか。
それとも0/1あるいは複数のカテゴリの分類する「判別」の問題でしょうか。

ランダムフォレストは各特徴量の重要度の出力がありますが、特徴量の寄与を見るのが主であるならば
まずは

- 回帰の場合
  　　重回帰分析、回帰木分析
- 判別の場合
  　　ロジスティック回帰分析、決定木分析

から入った方がいいと思います。特徴量の寄与が分かりやすいです。
これらの手法は精度がいまいちですので、さらに精度を求めつつ寄与も知りたい場合にランダムフォレスト等
を実施し、特徴量の寄与を比較するなどすると、よりはっきりしてくるかと思います。
調べたところOrangeにもこれら手法ができるようですのでお試しになってください。